# Multiple optional parameters in Luminus / Compojure routes?

Tags: clojure, routes, compojure, luminus

I would like to create a route that has multiple optional parameters, detected by the presence of a "keyword" in the URL, and processed in any order.

Examples:

```
http://localhost:3000/service1/param1/value1/param2/value2
http://localhost:3000/service1/param2/value2/param4/value4/param1/value1
```

Is this even possible? I could see putting together a macro to create the routes, but that creates at least a factorial of routes. Calls will come through maybe 1/hour, so I could handle slow response times. But is it reasonable to use a macro to create 5,000 routes for 7 optional parameters?

Comment: You could trivially look at the path and parse param1/value1/param2/value2 .. into a map {:param1 value1, :param2 value2 ...}

Answer (score 1):

You need to write or generate yourself a custom handler function that parses the uri string into parameters, sorts them into the correct order and invokes your target handlers with them.

Since you are using ring, the uri string can be found under key `:uri` in the ring request map.

Compojure can't be used for the dispatch because it is not designed to work the way you want to use it.

Here is a simplified example where the target handler is invoked with a hashmap of parsed parameters to illustrate the idea:

```
(defn handle
  [{:keys [uri] :as request}]
  (let [[root & more] (keep not-empty (clojure.string/split uri #"/")]
    (if (= "service1" root)
      (->> more
           (partition 2)
           (reduce (fn [acc [k v]]
                     (assoc acc
                       (keyword k) v) ;; TODO: parse value if necessary
                     )
                   {})
           ;; TODO: invoke your handler fn here
           )
      ;; TODO: invoke compojure handler for other routes with request here
      )))

(handle {:uri "/service1/param2/value2/param4/value4/param1/value1"})
;; {:param1 "value1", :param4 "value4", :param2 "value2"}
```